# Is logged data considered level data?

Tags: vector-autoregression, cointegration, vector-error-correction-model

Hi I'm new to VECM/VAR models. I read that we can use VECM when data is non-stationary at level but some form of cointegration exists.

By "level" does it mean it has to be the raw data? Or can the data be logged and I proceed to use VECM, assuming my logged data is non-stationary and have some form of cointegration?
Thanks!

Comment: logged is level

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Aksakal!